# How to get resolution of silverlight + XNA application

Tags: c#, silverlight, xna

I am developing a game using Silverlight and XNA framework. I wants to get the height and width of the mobile screen for running the app in any device. Means scaling of application should be supported to all devices.

```cs
public partial class GamePage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
   public static ContentManager contentManager;
   GameTimer timer;
   SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
   GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

   public GamePage()
   {
        InitializeComponent();

        //error at below line 
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

        contentManager = (System.Windows.Application.Current as App).Content;

        rand = new Random();

        // Create a timer for this page
        timer = new GameTimer();
        timer.UpdateInterval = TimeSpan.FromTicks(333333);
        timer.Update += OnUpdate;
        timer.Draw += OnDraw;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note I am not sure if this is available on mobile. `GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width or Height` will give you the devices screen resolution,

```
graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Height
graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.CurrentDisplayMode.Width
graphics.ApplyChanges();
```

**Edit:**

Using silverlight you must do this:

```
Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;
```

Also note the silverlight equivalent of `GraphicsDevciceManager` is `SharedGraphicsDeviceManager`

Comment: it is available but only in xna game....if you are doing xna plus silverlight then it gives the error

Comment: the best overloaded method match for Microdoft.XNA.framework.graphicsdevicemanager(micorsoft.xna.framework.game)has some invalid arguements

Comment: if i make changes in this line then that error is solved but other methods gives error                   class GamePage : Microsoft.XNA.Game

Comment: What is the actual error? Also try using `SharedGraphicsDeviceManager`

Answer (score 1):

`Application.Current.RootVisual.RenderSize` should give you that information.

Or you can try:

```cs
int ScreenWidth = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;  
int ScreenHeight = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
```